# Display GIF while data is loading from database with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

how i can  show a loading GIF image or a Qlabel update while i load data from database with QAbstractTableModel.i am new in pyqt5 and i tried it from last week but didn't understand how i can do that .

there are many example i found in stackoverflow but i really cannot deal with Qthread.i don't want to use timer for it as i can see in many examples are using qtimer. loading gif is automatically close while loading completed in table.
can anyone please show me how to do this and describes all things.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

class NumpyArrayModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, array, headers, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._array = array
        self._headers = headers
        self.r, self.c = np.shape(self.array)

    @property
    def array(self):
        return self._array

    @property
    def headers(self):
        return self._headers

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.r

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.c

    def headerData(self, p_int, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if p_int < len(self.headers):
                    return self.headers[p_int]
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return p_int + 1
        return

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if row < 0 or row >= self.rowCount():
            return None
        if column < 0 or column >= self.columnCount():
            return None
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self.array[row, column])
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role != QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if row < 0 or row >= self.rowCount():
            return False
        if column < 0 or column >= self.columnCount():
            return False
        self.array.values[row][column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

   
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.pathLE = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.pathLE)
        self.loadBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Load data", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.loadBtn)
        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        self.pandasTv = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.pandasTv)
        self.loadBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
        self.pandasTv.setSortingEnabled(True)


    def loadFile(self):
        self.pathLE.setText("Loading data")

        server = '190.11.71.09'
        database = ''
        username = 'Admin'
        passwd = ''
        conn= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                          server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + passwd)

        query="select * from database.dbo.tableName(nolock)"

       
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
        array = np.array(df.values)
        headers = df.columns.tolist()
        model = NumpyArrayModel(array, headers)
        self.pandasTv.setModel(model)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to display a GIF image.
Then learn how to trigger an action via a button.

Do not fall into the typical pit by implementing your action to

- display the GIF
- load the data
- hide the GIF
  as this ties down the one thread that triggered your action. This one thread is crucial to keep the UI updating.

So what you need to do when the button gets pressed:

- Spawn a new thread to execute some code

In the new thread the code to execute contains the above statements:

- show GIF
- load data
- hide GIF (even if data loading fails)

For showing, hiding and finally rendering the loaded data you will have to look out because now you try to modify the UI from another thread - this will need some kind of treatment. BTW this behaviour is not specific to Qt. You will find similar things in Java AWT and Swing.